# GORM events (beforeInsert) not called when saving in Controller

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy

I have a simple Domain class that is using "assigned" as the id generator. This is because I want to manually generate id's based on some other parameter and automate it by setting the id parameter when the "beforeInsert" event is called. The problem is that for some reason, `beforeInsert()` is never called when saving a new domain object to the
database from a controller. Why is it not working?

PS: The error I get is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Entity [Testy : (unsaved)] has null identifier when identifier strategy is manual assignment. Assign an appropriate identifier before persisting.
```

Testy domain class:

```java
import grails.mongodb.MongoEntity
import org.bson.types.ObjectId


class Testy implements MongoEntity<Testy> {

    ObjectId id

    Integer i

    static mapping = {
        id generator: "assigned"
        collection "testy"
        database "test"
    }

    static constraints = {
        i nullable: false
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        id = new ObjectId()
        return true
    }
}
```

TestyController

```java
package hegardt.backend.grails

import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus

class TestyController {

    @Transactional
    def save() {
        Testy instance = new Testy()
        bindData(instance, request.getJSON())

        instance.validate()
        if (instance.hasErrors()) {
            respond instance.errors, view: 'create' // STATUS CODE 422
            return
        }

        instance.insert(flush: true)

        render HttpStatus.OK
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you invoke `instance.save(flush: true)` instead of `instance.insert(flush: true)`?

Comment: The same thing, nothing 

Comment: We have some basic test coverage of `beforeInsert` at https://github.com/grails/gorm-mongodb/blob/9ae5e3e5a655ce49f86568e9f3c4124f66ff867f/grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb/src/test/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/mongo/BeforeInsertUpdateSpec.groovy.  That might help.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/gorm-mongodb/issues with a link to a sample app, we can investigate. Thank you for your feedback.